# gradle - execution order issue

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a project that looks like this.

```
root
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
    project1
         build.gradle

    project2
         build.gradle

    project3
         build.gradle

    project4
         build.gradle
```

settings.gradle looks like this.

```
include ':project1', ':project2', ':project3', ':project4'
```

build.gradle (from root)

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    compile project(':project1')
    compile project(':project2')
    compile project(':project3')
    compile project(':project4')
}
```

So basically, I want 'project1' to be built first before project2, 3, 4, because it needs to download our internal dependency(jar and some schema files) so that project2, 3 and 4 will be able to extract artifacts from the schema files(from project1).

But when I run it, i see standard output from project2 and 3 printed first before project1 runs.

Especially project2 contains many tasks(type: JavaExec) which run this type of arguments.

```
  main = 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler'
  classpath "${BUILDROOT}/project1/${COMMON_DENEPDENCY_FILE}"
  args "-src", "${projectDir}/src/main/java", "-d", "build/generated", "-srconly", "${projectDir}/xml/schema/example1.xsd", "${projectDir}/xml/schema/example1.xsdconfig"
```

One of the tasks looks like this. I have several tasks that look like this in project2. So project1 has to be fully built before project2 and project3 run.

build.gradle from project2

```
task xmlbeansExample2(dependsOn: xmlbeansExample1, type: JavaExec) {
  println "Example2 is running"
  main = 'org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.tool.SchemaCompiler'
  classpath "${BUILDROOT}/common/${COMMON_DENEPDENCY_FILE}"
  args "-src", "${projectDir}/src/main/java", "-d", "build/generated", "-srconly", "${projectDir}/xml/schema/example2.xsd", "${projectDir}/xml/schema/example2.xsdconfig"
  println "Example2 is done"
}
task handleSchema(dependsOn: ['xmlbeansExample1', 'xmlbeansExample2'])

build.dependsOn handleSchema, jar
```

When I run 'gradle build' from the root or project2, I see the printout from project2 first.

Is there something wrong with my layout?

My team is migrating from Ant to Gradle, but gradle seems a little different from Ant execution. Maybe I am little misunderstood about the gradle.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for root project it's unnecessary to specify child modules as a dependencies.

If your modules are dependant from another one you should clearly defined this dependency.

```
// project2/build.gradle
dependencies {
    compile project(':project1')
}
```